# Determine Excel Template Path

Tags: excel, templates, excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel 2007 template that I want to allow others to be able to use. As part of the code I need to know where the template was originally located, since the location can be different based upon where he user places it. When a new workbook is created form the template, it has no value in the ActiveWorkBook.Path value, this is not populated until it is saved somewhere.

Is there any way to determine the path of the template from which the workbook was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the template has a unique name, and you know what drive it is stored on you could use something like:

```
Function GetTemplatePath(drive As String, templateName As String) As String

    Dim cmd As String, result As String
    cmd = "CMD /C DIR """ & drive & ":\*" & templateName & """ /S /B /A:-D"

    On Error Resume Next
    result = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)(0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If InStr(result, "\") Then
        GetTemplatePath = Left(result, InStrRev(result, "\"))
    Else
        GetTemplatePath = vbNullString
    End If

End Function
```

You would use it like so:

```
Dim filePath As String

filePath = GetTemplatePath("C", "MyTemplate.xltx")

Debug.Print filePath
```

Comment: Thanks - that is an interesting approach, however, I don't know that I will be able to determine a drive / location where the user will store the template. The idea is that the template will be stored in the same directory where other files used by the Excel application will be stored, and thus those other files can be easily located.
For the time being, I will use a dummy workbook rather than a template and have the VBA code run a SaveAs at the end of processing which will prevent the dummy workbook from being overwritten with a populated workbook.

Comment: 99.9% of the time the drive is going to be `C:\ ` - but you could just use: `filePath = GetTemplatePath(Left(CurDir, 1), "MyTemplate.xltx")` if you are not sure